# Can I fix or troubleshoot my 14–42 mm lens that isn't working with Olympus OM-D E-M10 Mark II?

Tags: lens, troubleshooting, error, olympus-omd

I have an Olympus OM-D E-M10 Mark II camera with two lenses: 14–42 mm and 40–150 mm. When photographing the rain, suddenly the 14–42 mm lens stopped working giving the following error: "Check the condition of the lens".

I've already cleaned and dried the machine and lens terminals with heat, but it didn't work. I took one or two more photos, and after that, it's not working again.

I used another 14–42 mm lens and it gave the same error. With my 40–150 mm it works well.

Is there anything I can do to fix or use my 14–42 mm lens again?